# Optimize MySQL aggregate query for a single table with 28 million rows

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I need help optimizing a query. There's a pivot table holding user IDs matched with notification IDs per user:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+
| id | user_id | notification_id |
+----+---------+-----------------+
|  1 |     234 |               3 |
|  2 |     546 |              34 |
|  3 |     646 |              11 |
+----+---------+-----------------+
```

Both `user_id` and `notification_id` are foreign keys. The table has **~28 million** rows.

The idea is to get 100 IDs of users who have more than 120 notifications, ordered by the ones with most notifications:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(feed_notification_id) AS notification_count 
FROM sd_user_feed_notification
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING notification_count >= 120
ORDER BY notification_count DESC
LIMIT 100
```

The problem is that the query above runs for over 200s, as it has to basically go through all the rows to aggregate the notifications.

The foreign keys are already indexes. The query itself is pretty straightforward.

Is there any way to optimize it?

**MySQL version: 5.6**

Comment: Let MySQL use more RAM, that's about it. Ingredients: a server with more RAM. Increase the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Once the indexes are in RAM, the I/O is much faster, therefore - you'll achieve your goal.

Comment: What foreign keys? I do not see any joins in your query. Is the table ```sd_user_feed_notification``` a view?

Comment: @SloanThrasher True, there's no `JOIN`. What I meant is that the 2 fields are automatically indexes, because they are foreign keys to 2 other tables: `users` and `notifications`. Do you suggest that this doesn't have any impact on the query speed? Might be. I'm here to learn.

Comment: @SloanThrasher keys won't help here, it's a full table scan, there's no condition that can reduce the data set that needs to be looked at. If the `notification_count` existed as a value in a column, that's a different story. But it does not.

Comment: @NB: If there was a multi-column index on user_id and notification_id, wouldn't MySQL scan the index instead of the table?

Comment: Just because they are FK doesn't mean that their indexes will be used (or that an index exists)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to see the PK and some other details.

Comment: If there is no need to check for `NULL`, use `COUNT(*)`, not `COUNT(feed_notification_id)`.

Comment: It is either a full table scan (slower) or a full index scan (faster); please provide`SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no composite index on `(user_id, feed_notification_id)`, then likely the query isn't being satisfied entirely from an index. That is, the execution plan is performing lookups to the underlying table pages, to check if `feed_notification_id` is NULL. (A `COUNT(expr)` aggregate will not include rows where the expression evaluates to NULL.)

We would (likley) get better performance with a query that can be satisfied from an index, for example, by removing the reference to `feed_notification_id` column.

If we are guaranteed that `feed_notification_id` is NOT NULL, then this would get us an equivalent result:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT user_id
     , COUNT(1) AS notification_count 
  FROM sd_user_feed_notification
 GROUP BY user_id
```

(We expect the EXPLAIN output to show "Using index" in the Extra column.)

So the query would be a full scan of just an index, with no lookups to the underlying table.

---

That's still going to need to evaluate 28 million rows.
A
And with the `ORDER BY` on the aggregate expression, there's no getting around the "Using filesort" operation.

---

If we have to stick with the existing query, then optimal performance (of that query) would be with a composite index `ON sd_user_feed_notification (user_id, feed_notification_id)`.

And adding that index would render an index `ON sd_user_feed_notification (user_id)` redundant.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Q: (1) Should I then remove the single indexes on user_id and notification_id and stick to the compound one only in the case of my query?

Q: (2) Wouldn't this affect other queries ran against the table?

A:  If we add the composite index on `(user_id,feed_notification_id)`, then we can remove the index on just `(user_id)`.  This composite index is suitable for supporting a foreign key constraint.

Any query that was benefiting from the old (singleton `user_id` column) index can benefit from the replacement (composite) index (with `user_id` as the leading column.)

And some queries will benefit more, eliminating lookups to pages in the underlying table (to retrieve values of `notification_id`.)

The replacement index will be larger, but it will work the same, in terms of improving performance by eliminating vast swaths of rows when we're looking for rows related to a single user.

---

The new composite index is *not* a replacement for the index on the `feed_notification_id` column.

We would still need an index that has that column as the leading column. (We could replace it with a composite index on `(feed_notification_id,user_id)`.

The *order* of columns in an index is significant.

---

If the combination of (user_id,feed_notification_id) is UNIQUE, then we can define the index as a UNIQUE index, and enforce that.

Also, if this table is purely a linkage/association/join table, and is not an entity table (i.e. there are no foreign key references to this table), then for performance, I would consider dropping the `id` column (presumably that's defined as the `PRIMARY` (cluster) key.

I would tend towards a table definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sd_user_feed_notification
( user_id               INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK ref user.id'
, feed_notification_id  INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK ref feed_notification.id'
, PRIMARY KEY (user_id, feed_notification_id)
, KEY sd_user_feed_notification_IX (feed_notification_id, user_id)

, CONSTRAINT FK_sd_user_feed_notification_user 
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)              REFERENCES sd_user (id) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE 

, CONSTRAINT FK_sd_user_feed_notification_feed
  FOREIGN KEY (feed_notification_id) REFERENCES sd_feed_notification (id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: (1) Should I then remove the single indexes on `user_id` and `notification_id` and stick to the compound one only in the case of my query? (2) Wouldn't this affect other queries ran against the table?

Comment: (1) if we add the composite index on `(user_id,feed_notification_id)` then we can (and should) drop the key on singleton column `userid`. But we need do need to keep the other index, the one with leading column `feed_notification_id`. (2) yes, other queries referencing the table will choose which indexes to use. our goal is to have a suitable indexes available to the queries we run.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know I tried out your suggestions, all except removing the `id` column. Meaning: I set the composite index on `(user_id, feed_notification_id)`, both `INDEX` and `UNIQUE`, separately. I also tried different column order on the composite index. Unfortunately, none of these actions helped to make the query faster. My guess is there are other factors involved a well (someone suggested extending DB RAM, etc.). In any case, I very much appreciate the help and the time you spent on it. I'm sure the suggestions are valid, they simply are not enough in my case.

Comment: @lesssugar: my very *first* suggestion was to *modify* the query, to remove the reference to `feed_notification_id` column, and replace that with a literal.

Comment: Sure, I did that as well, just forgot to mention it.

Comment: Maybe my answer wasn't clear. The rigmarole with the replacement indexes (in the context of optimizing that query) was an *alternative* to making changes to the query. The query does need to crank through every flipping row in the table, getting the query satisfied from a covering index (EXPLAIN output shows "Using index") is likely to be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

`sd_user_feed_notification` sounds like a mapping table between `user` and `feed_notification`.  If so, get rid of the FKs and follow the rules given [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for many-to-many tables.  That will include

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, notification_id),  -- implies UNIQUE
INDEX(notification_id, user_id)         -- saying UNIQUE would be redundant
```

(or vice versa).  At which point all of the above comments are handled.  Furthermore the table has only 2 columns, so it is as small as an index -- either is as fast as it can be.

In virtually cases, get rid of `INDEX(a)` when you add `INDEX(a,b)`.  But do *not* drop `INDEX(b)`.  The order of the columns in a composite index is important.  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)